# Can a PowerBook or MacBook be configured to automatically wake when power is connected?

Tags: macbook-pro, leopard, audio, power

I'm looking to turn an old Mac laptop into a "car-puter". However, I don't want to drain the battery on either the laptop or the car. Is there a way to configure it so that the computer automatically wakes up when plugged into power? (I know that it can be woken via ethernet, but I don't know how I can turn that to my advantage.)

My specific use case is a late-model [PowerBook G4](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/powerbook_g4/stats/powerbook_g4_1.5_15_2.html) running 10.5, but I'm also curious about whether this can be done with other models or OS versions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you indicated, this does depend on the specifics of the hardware - but the `pmset acwake` command is used to read or change the intended wake on power change status for a Mac.

The [man page for pmset](https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/pmset.html) goes into some detail how to use this command line tool to change settings.

I couldn't find a reference that calls out which models work with this setting - you may have to experiment or do some more research.

Comment: pmset looks like it may fit the bill, thanks! I've also updated the question with a link to the PowerBook model I'm using.